# How to override an ASP.NET Core configuration array setting reducing length of the array

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration

I have an ASP.NET Core app with `appsettings.json` config file. One of the settings in the file is represented by the array of objects, like this:

```
{
  "Globalization": {
    "Languages": [
      {
        "DisplayName": "Ru",
        "Code": "ru"
      },
      {
        "DisplayName": "En",
        "Code": "en"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In our CI system we use environment variables to override the configuration settings from file. It turns out that I can only override existing items or add new items to the array, but I can’t reduce the number of items using index notation (`"Globalization__Languages__0__DisplayName"` etc.).

And it’s the same with `appsettings.{Environment}.json`, I still have two language options even if I have just one item in it.

Of course I can make the base config empty or invent some other workaround, but am  I missing something? Is there any way to neatly override the settings reducing the number of items (preferably with the help of environment variables)?

Answer (score 3):

[Microsoft community](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/src) made a very bad design decision to make arrays work in that way (IMHO).

As a solution we worked it out as the follows:

```json
{
  "Globalization": {
    "Languages": "ru|Ru,en|En"
  }
}
```

and then:

```cs
var langs = Configuration.GetSection("Globalization:Languages")
    .Value.Split(',')
    .Select(x => x.Split('|'))
    .Select(x => new { Code = x[0], DisplayName = x[1] })
    .ToArray();
```

My proposal is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36569#issuecomment-949563504).